# How to dereference an object in Python?

Tags: python, printing

I have a function with returns a tuple:

```
def gradiant(params, data):
    Q1 = params[0]
    Q2 = params[1]
    dQ1 = sum(2*(y_i - Q1*x_i - Q2)*(x_i) for x_i, y_i in data)
    dQ2 = sum(-2*(y-i - Q1*x_i - Q2) for x_i, y_i in data)
    return (dQ1, dQ2)
```

I'm trying to print the returned values:

```
grad = gradiant(params, Data)
for x in grad: print(x)
```

Output:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fdfe009adc0>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fdfe009a5f0>
```

How do I get to print the integer values?

Comment: Can you tell us the contents of `params` and `Data` so that we can try it out and see what happens?

Comment: That's odd. You should get a tuple of numbers from that function. Unless you've redefined `sum`...

Comment: The builtin `sum` doesn't return a generator... so a redefined `sum` may explain it. What does `print(type(sum))` within the function say?

Comment: @tdelaney <type 'function'>

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 data= [(2,3), (3,4), (4,5)], params = [-9, -5]

Comment: Excellent! The builtin `sum` function would be `<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>`, so you have some other function named `sum` that returns generators.  `sum.__module__` should tell you where it is from.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `y-i` instead of `y_i`. It produced a `NameError` for me. I fixed the typo and it worked fine (I assume, anyway - it printed two numbers).

However, the more interesting issue is how errors are handled within generator expressions (as the typo was part of the generator expression you sent to `sum()`). I got a `NameError`, but you got generator expression objects. Look at this function call with an unpacked generator that should contain a `TypeError`:

```
>>> print(*(''.join(item2) for item2 in range(3)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: print() argument after * must be a sequence, not generator
```

Now let's see what we get by printing the actual object:

```
>>> print(''.join(item2) for item2 in range(3))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000028945E8>
```

That makes some sense, as generators are lazily evaluated and it was never actually called. But let's see what happens when we send it to `list()`, which should force evaluation:

```
>>> print(list(''.join(item2) for item2 in range(3)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

There's the expected error.

How about a valid generator that contains an invalid generator?

```
>>> print(*(list(''.join(item2) for item2 in range(3)) for i in range(1)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: print() argument after * must be a sequence, not generator
```

The same uninformative error.

What if we use a `list` comprehension instead of a generator expression?

```
>>> print(*[''.join(item2) for item2 in range(3)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

We get the informative error we were expecting.

Unfortunately, I don't know why this happens, but be extra-careful with generator expressions.